# Joomla 3.10 admin not working after upgrade to PHP 8

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, versions

My provider has upgraded the PHP version from 7.4 to 8.1. I'm working with Joomla 3.10 and thought that no actions were needed since PHP 8 is recommended for Joomla 3.10.

Since the upgrade was done, I have no more access to my Joomla administration (http error 500). I also cannot downgrade to PHP 7.4.

Is there any turnaround to get access to the Joomla administration? Or at least to the content of all the modules of Joomla in order to copy/paste the content into a new environment?

Comment: I had the same issue using a revised Joomla Template built on J3.9.28 from years ago. I loved the template and spent a fortune to get it customized. We use GoDaddy hosting and discovered that all the extensions and plugins only worked on PHP 7.4. GoDaddy is insisting we upgrade to a higher PHP version. When I did upgrade to PHP 8.0, many of the features didn't work. One of the plugins we use is VirtueMart 3.6.0 10113 (ecommerce shopping cart) and you just get a spinning wheel when you try to add to the shopping cart live. I was able to revert back to PHP 7.4 and it worked again. So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you **switch your PHP to 8.0**?

**Joomla 3.10** is **not compatible with PHP 8.1**.

The Joomla 3.10 core is compatible with PHP 8.0. Some non-core extensions might not be compatible with PHP 8.0.

When you get white screens the error reporting is set to off. To switch error reporting on (and see the real errors), you have to configure Joomla's error reporting to "maximum". To do that: in `configuration.php` change `public $error_reporting = 'default';` to `public $error_reporting = 'maximum';` to display errors.

Comment: You're wrong with your statements. Joomla says 3.x works with 8.0 (recommended). My Joomla sites (3.10) work with 8.1.11.

The problem lies in template or extension.

Comment: PHP 8.0 is different than PHP 8.1 for Joomla 3. There are so many deprecated warnings while using Joomla 3.10 with PHP 8.1. It may be working for you but you might have turned off the error display.

Comment: The problem was due to an extension. Since my provider didn't downgrade the PHP version, i had to transfer the content of the site, downgrade to PHP 7.4, uninstall the extension and retransfer the content!